# How to set Dynamic quota configuration on kafka using java

Tags: apache-kafka, throttling

I'm trying to set default quota to 0 for all the clients 
so that initially they should not send/consume any messages until
overriding the quota configuration.

I have tried using below command but couldn't achieve it.

```
./bin/kafka-configs.sh  
        --zookeeper <zookeeperhost> 
        --alter --add-config 'producer_byte_rate=0,consumer_byte_rate=0' 
        --entity-type clients 
        --entity-default
```

Can someone explain how to achieve it?

Comment: Which Kafka broker version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

By design, Quotas can't be used to prevent users from producing or consuming, even by setting them to 0. They can only be used to ensure that users stay within defined throughput/request rates.

To prevent users from producing/consuming messages, you need to use ACLs, see the [relevent section](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz) in the documentation to set them properly.